# Solving for (or approximating) $x$ in $\frac{x-\sin x}{x^{0.4}} = c$

Tags: numerical-methods

I'm an engineer and I'm deducting a formula, and I found a BIG problem: I can't isolate $x$.

The formula is:
$$\frac{x-\sin x}{x^{0.4}} = c$$
where $c$ is a constant.

How to find the value for $x$, or at least a good approximation?

Comment: What is the range of $c$ in your application? It makes a difference if you look for solutions for small $c$, or for rather large $c$.

Comment: I'm sorry, C can vary a lot but in most of my tests i'd say that C > 2

Comment: for $c>5.278$ there are more than one value for $x$, I mean that the function in the RHS is not invertible.

Comment: What precision do you need?

Comment: 0,01 error (max)

Answer (score 2):

The leading term of $x-\sin x$ is $\frac{x^3}6$. This would result in a first approximation of $x=(6c)^{1/2.6}$ for smallish values of $c$.

For larger values of $c$ one would use that $|\sin x|\le  1$ to get approximately $x=c^{1/0.6}$.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Newton-Raphson, with $c^{\frac{5}{3}}$ as initial guess. If $c$ is close to $0$ (e.g. in $(-1, 1)$), you could use $\sqrt[2.6]{6c}$ instead.

The function oscillates around $x^{\frac{3}{5}}$ and is nice and smooth. This should work fine.

I tested it for $c= 10$ and within 3 iterations the error was tiny. Depending on the required accuracy, you can easily add more iterations.

Comment: Hello robby, thanks for the answer i'm really happy you could find an good approximation. Could you show me the precise method and final formula to find the value of x?

Comment: Sure, have a look here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ftfaw0w5aq . The function $a$ takes an initial guess ($x$) and a target value ($c$) and returns a better approximation.

Comment: Thanks very much!! One more question: Why you had c^5/3 as an inital guess?

Comment: See Lutz Lehmann's answer. Since, for values "far" from 0, $\frac{x - \sin x}{x^{0.4}} \approxeq \frac{x}{x^{0.4}}$, that approximation works well enough for an initial guess.

Comment: Thanks robby, i've tested many iterations and it's a sucess!! But the error suddenly stops decreasing after some iterations, is that normal?

Comment: That is mostly due to numerical issues. A computer or calculator has a limit on its precision.

Answer (score 1):

There is no analytical function that will give you x = f(c). I can recommend Wolfram Alpha to get a quick insight into the problem: (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x+-+sinx%29+%2Fx%5E0.4+%3D+10+solve+for+x).

You get immediately a plot of your function. Hope that helps a bit

Answer (score 1):

Here is the graph of the inverse of
$$f(x)=\frac{x-\sin x}{x^{0.4}}$$
as you can see it is not a function. For some value of $c$ there are more than one $x$, even three in some intervals.

For $c=3$ we have $x_1\approx 4.5;\;x_2\approx 6.35;\;x_3\approx 7.83$.

For $c=3.3$ we have $x\approx 8.55$.

I used [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org), plotted $f(x)$ and to get the inverse I took its symmetric with respect to the bisector of the first quadrant. This gives fine approximations for any $c$.

$$
$$
[image]